# Prevent element from getting focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Essentially is it possible to stop an element, in my case a `button` element from getting focus in javascript?

What I am trying to achieve is an AngularJS directive that when it gets focus will show a number of buttons/UI elements. Using the `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` directives this is easily achieved however when I try to click any of the buttons, the button gains focus so the div no longer has focus, `ng-blur` is triggered and the buttons are hidden.

I want the buttons to stay visible whilst the directive element has focus and be clickable.

[Here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NRZWmcFgtSbZl04BkBej?p=preview) showing this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it would have been simpler not to use any focusable element such as `<button>`s and `<a>` anchor tags. You can use a div that is not focusable and style it as a button, bind your `ng` event at that div and it should solve your problems. You gain the non-focusable advantage and still get to append your events in that particular element.

**focusableDiv** directive

change

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="add()" ng-show="isFocused">Action</button>
```

to

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()" ng-show="isFocused">Action</div>
```

Note: the changes above assumes that you are using bootstrap-css to style your `<div>` button

See this [plunker update](http://plnkr.co/edit/J157dQh14Vo7Zh6kj0Vk?p=preview)

Comment: Exactly what we came up with below. Simple and works, only note to add is you might want to remove `user-select` styles (and variations) so on multiple clicks the default text select behavior is suppressed.

Comment: As far as I know, bootstrap-css buttons `btn` have their initial `user-select`'s suppressed.

Comment: Correct they do, sorry by you I meant other readers who may not be using Bootstrap and are wanting the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You know....you don't have to actually click the button.

```
'<button class="btn" ng-focus="add()" ng-show="isFocused">Action</button>' +
```

Fork of your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7uoOF5HS0yrsW5kquodA?p=preview

Comment: This is clever, however focus is still removed from the div element and the button(s) disappear, i would like it to stay visible, so for example the button could be interacted with multiple times and only hidden when the main element loses focus.

Comment: Haha ok, wasn't sure of that would work for you or not. I'll have to think about this a little more....it's kind of tricky.

Comment: Following your line of thought, if I just make the UI elements basic block elements, i.e. a `div` instead of a `button` they will not gain focus and it should just work. Simple! thank you for the inspiration haha!